# LIBCMTD conflicts warning when linking with opensssl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl

I use Visual Studio 2017 to compile my application with /MDd compiler switch. When I try to link openssl to my application, it gives me the following warning:

> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of
>   other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

I have built openssl myself using the following command:

> perl Configure Debug-VC-WIN32 no-shared no-stdio no-ui no-filenames no-engine no-dso no-idea no-sock --prefix=some_path --openssldir=some_path

Before executing nmake, I modified the following line in the generated makefile to change it from /MT to /MDd:

> LIB_CFLAGS=/Zi /Fdossl_static /MT /Zl